# Segmentation fault while trying to declare a 5D array in a C Program

Tags: c, memory, fortran, segmentation-fault

I am converting a program from fortran77 to C Programming Language, In the fortran program a 5D array is declared as shown below, and the code compiles and executes well. But when I convert the same code to C with the same values, the C code compiles but it gives Segmentation fault.

If this issue is because of the different standard layout of multidimensional arrays memory allocation between the two languages, I have tried all dimension combinations while declaring the array in C, and in all cases it also gives a 'Segmentation fault'.

I have also tired the 'calloc' technique shown below, and it works but I don't know how to assign values to the globally declared array.

Note: The segmentation fault is at the declaration step (i.e. The program stops there)

So basically my questions are:
- Why does it works in fortran but not in C ?, and,
- How to solve this issues in C ?

```fortran
 ! Fortran77 Code
  parameter (i2maxbin=38)     
  parameter (imaxbin=20)       
  parameter (Nid=10)      
  real*8 dNdpt(Nid,i2maxbin,imaxbin,imaxbin,imaxbin)
```

---

```c
 /* C Code */
  const int i2maxbin = 38;
  const int imaxbin = 20;
  const int nID = 10;
  double dNdpt[nID][i2maxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin];

 /* Declaring using calloc */
double (*dNdpt)[nID][i2maxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin] = 
calloc(sizeof(*dNdpt), 38);

for(int i = 0; i < nID; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < i2maxbin; j++)
    {
        dNdpt[i][j][0][0][0] = 12.22673423;
    }        
}

When executing it gives me this error

error: assignment to expression with array type
         dNdpt[i][j][0][0][0] = 12.22673423;
                              ^
```

Comment: The C code is attempting to use *VLA* (variable length arrays) -- have no idea about Fortran. VLA's are tipically implemented on the stack; and C has, tipically, a small(ish) stack space. Instead of `const int` try `#define`.

Comment: It is not possible to not compile and give a segfault. Which one happens?

Comment: That’s a very large amount of data you are trying to allocate on the stack, maybe best done using malloc

Comment: The most probable reason is that the system doesn't allow you to use much memory. It can be changed (at least in GCC) by setting some options in the compilation. Google (or duckduckgo better :)) mcmodel=medium

Comment: Also the amount of memory you are allowed to use depends on wether you are using local variables (stack is very limited) or global ones. Or to be more precise, non-static vs static variables.

Comment: That array will be over 20 MiB of space. Local non-static variables (a.k.a. automatic variables) as usually stored on the (very limited) stack. On Windows the default stack size for a process is only a single megabyte, 5% of what's needed for your array.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, Thanks for the note, I will edit it in the question :)

Comment: What is the reason for ` /* Declaring using calloc */
double (*dNdpt)[nID][i2maxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin] = 
calloc(sizeof(*dNdpt), 38);` You already created the variable in `double dNdpt[nID][i2maxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin];` you only have to assign the value 0 to the elements, 5 level nested loop, to do a proper initialization (when not automatically done already).

Comment: @BobEhab this page may also be useful (about the use of malloc and multi-dim array pointer) https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. places the array in file scope rather than on the stack
2. cleanly compiles
3. avoids the use of dynamic memory allocation/free'ing
4. cleanly runs and exits without crashing
5. avoids using VLAs

And now the proposed code:

```
#define i2maxbin  38
#define imaxbin   20
#define nID       10



double dNptr[nID][i2maxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin][imaxbin];


int main( void )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nID; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i2maxbin; j++)
        {
            dNptr[i][j][0][0][0] = 12.22673423;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack size in C and also in C++ is very limited, generally, a 1D-array of maximum 1e5 size is allowed, and if we assume "double" size as 8 bytes then that translates into maximum memory of 8*1e5 bytes.

Now, let's look at your 5D-array, it's trying to allocate 10*38*20*20*20 = 3,040,000 "double" units which when converted into the memory is 24,320,000 bytes which is well above the allotted stack size in C or C++.
That's why you are getting a SEG-FAULT.

You can try initializing the array globally that way it is allocated heap memory which is typically bigger than the stack memory, even then the max size is limited to 8*7*1e5 bytes at max(depends on your machine).

Comment: We are talking about double precision variables (8-byte) so 24,320.000 bytes. The stack size on Windows is limited quite a bit (but can be increased), on Linux it is depending on the (u)limit setting. I don't think 24Mb is large for the stack but not extremely. There is probably a compiler option to allocate these type of arrays on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You solve it by creating the array on the heap instead of the stack.

```
double* dNdpt = malloc(sizeof(double)*nID*i2maxbin*imaxbin*imaxbin*imaxbin);
```

then keep track of where you are in this gigantic array by calculating the index

a simpler example :

```
double* my2dim = malloc(sizeof(double)*10*20); // 10 rows 20 cols

my2dim[3][2] = 10.0 would be written *(my2dim + 3 * 20 + 2) = 10.0;
```